# In NGiNX my try_files is trying to get a php file in the wrong place

Tags: nginx

Here is a sample of my configs:

```
root    /usr/local/html/website/public/;

location ~* auth/v1/* {
            try_files /auth.php?$args $uri/;
    }
#       location = /auth {return 301 http://website.com.jn/auth/v1/about;}
#       location = /auth/ {return 301 http://website.com.jn/auth/v1/about;}
#       location = /auth/v1 {return 301 http://website.com.jn/auth/v1/about;}
#       location = /auth/v1/ {return 301 http://website.com.jn/auth/v1/about;}
#       location ~* /auth/v1/* {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ /auth.php?$args;
#       }
```

Error:

```
open() "/usr/local/html/website/public/auth/v1/about" failed (2: No such file or directory),
```

Like you can see I tried different things but it does not work. The auth.php is found in "/usr/local/html/website/public/".

How can I point to the right place to get auth.php?

Using NGiNX 1.6 on Mac OS X.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? BTW, your `location`s regexp probably match something you don't want it to match.

Comment: I am trying to get the auth.php file found here: /usr/local/html/website/public/

Comment: What is the URL you tried to access when the error above happened?

Comment: Also, please show the complete nginx configuration.